# Discounted payback period: java formula

Tags: java, math

I am trying to calculate the discounted payback period using this but it keeps failing the test:

```
//test method 
@Test
public void testCalculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod() {
    double initialInvestment = 10000.0;
    List<Double> cashFlows = Arrays.asList(1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0);
    double discountRate = 5.0;
    double expResult = 4.37; 
    double result = calculations.calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod(cashFlows, discountRate);
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.01); 
}
//calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod method: 
 public static double calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod(Double initialInvestment, List<Double> cashFlows, double discountRate) {
    double cumulativeDiscountedCashFlow = -initialInvestment;
    int period = 0;
    while (cumulativeDiscountedCashFlow < 0 && period < cashFlows.size()) {
        cumulativeDiscountedCashFlow += (cashFlows.get(period) / Math.pow(1 + discountRate, period));
        period++;
    }
    if (period > 0 && period < cashFlows.size()) {
        double lastNegativeDiscountedCashFlow = cumulativeDiscountedCashFlow - (cashFlows.get(period - 1) / Math.pow(1 + discountRate, period - 1));
        double fraction = -lastNegativeDiscountedCashFlow / (cashFlows.get(period) / Math.pow(1 + discountRate, period));
        period += fraction;
    }
    return period;
}
```

So instead of giving 4.37, the answer its giving is 5. How do I correct the main method so that test can pass?

Comment: Wondering what that is and why it has to be a "negative".    -lastNegativeDiscountedCashFlow     Also it would be done safer with circular brackets to define the precedence order of the calculations.

Comment: The method `calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod` return type in signature is `double` but you return `int` at the end of method!

Comment: are you calling your method with the correct values? you provide a calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod() with 3 params, but you call it with 2 params. I assume you have an overload with 2 params that provides a default value that may be different from the test case initialInvestment?

Comment: @SamuelMarchant its to determine the fractional part of the "period" when the cumulative discounted cash flow becomes positive. also, i tried wrapping it in brackets nothing worked.

Comment: @HosseinTaghizad I changed the return type to double return (double) period. but no change.

Comment: Do you pass the `initialInvestment` to the `calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod` method? Can't see it in the test method.

Comment: In your method `calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod`, the contents of the if statement never executes since the `period < cashFlows.size()` condition always evaluates to `false`. If you closely look on the while loop above, you can see the exits when `period` is greater than or equal to `cashFlows.size()`. Which means by the time the if statement is executed, `period` is already greater than or equals to `cashFlows.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation of method *calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod()*. It takes *initial investment*, *discount rate*, and *cash flow list* as input and returns Discounted Payback Period (DPP).

```
public static double calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod(double initialInvestment, double discountRate, List<Double> cashFlows) {
    cashFlows.add(0, -initialInvestment);
    List<Double> PV = new ArrayList<>();    //Present Value
    List<Double> DCF = new ArrayList<>();   //Discounted Cash Flow
    List<Double> CCF = new ArrayList<>();   //Cumulative Discounted Cash Flow
    CCF.add(0, -initialInvestment);
    int x = 0;    //x is the last time period where CCF was negative
    double y = 0; //y is the absolute value of the CCF at the end of period X
    for (int j = 0; j < cashFlows.size(); j++) {
        PV.add(j, 1 / Math.pow((1 + discountRate), j));
        DCF.add(j, cashFlows.get(j) * PV.get(j));
        CCF.add(j, DCF.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum());
        if (CCF.get(j) > 0) {
            x = j - 1;
            y = Math.abs(CCF.get(x));
        }
    }
    double z = DCF.get(x + 1);  //z is the value of the DCF in the next period after x
    return x + y / z;     //The Discounted Payback Period (DPP) is x + y/z
}
```

Calling it with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double initialInvestment = 10000.0;
    double discountRate = .05;
    List<Double> cashFlows = Stream.of(1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    double DDP = DiscountedPaybackPeriod.calculateDiscountedPaybackPeriod(initialInvestment, discountRate, cashFlows);
    System.out.println(DDP);
}
```

retuned `DDP = 4.344911875`